# Python get file relative to command line user

Tags: python, file, command-line

I'm writing a python script that will be aliased and run from various directories like this:

```
# working
python myScript.py file.txt
```

or:

```
# not working
python script/myScript.py other_file.txt
```

I'm referencing the file input like this:

```
file = sys.argv[1]
```

How can I have the script look for the file based on the command line users location instead of relative to the script's location?

Comment: That's how it works by default, at least on my machine.

Comment: your input file will be looked up in the directory you typed the command. what's the error message you got? the error could be from not being able to find the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import os

print(os.getcwd())
```

This will give you the current working directory(cwd). And using other functions like `os.path.join`, you can achieve what you want.

Full example:

```
import os
import sys

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print('Not enough arguments.')
        sys.exit(1)

    print('Current working directory: %s' % os.getcwd())
    print('What you want: %s' % os.path.join(os.getcwd(), sys.argv[1]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Try using it.